# What MySQL datatype corresponds to an embedded object

Tags: java, mysql, orm

I have the following in an entity class

```
 @Embedded
    @Valid
    private Address address = new Address();
```

How do I make a MySQL datatype for this? Do I have to create a user-defined datatype with datatypes representing the class fields of the Address object?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create your own type with MySQL. To do what you want to achieve, you will need to serialize your object before adding it into the database with any text type.